# Code to display next day from assigned date

Tags: c++, date

I've been trying to write some code that gives me the next day from a date that has been gathered from user-input. here's my code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

    int daysMonth(int iMonth)
{
    if (iMonth >= 1 && iMonth <= 12)
    {
      if (iMonth == 2)
        return 28;

      if (iMonth == 4 || iMonth == 6 || iMonth == 9 || iMonth == 11)
        return 30;

        return 31;
    }
    return 0;
}

void nextDay (int iD, int iMonth, int iY)
{
    int daysM = daysMonth(iMonth);

            if (iD != daysM)
            {
                iD = iD + 1;
                iMonth = iMonth;
                iY = iY;
            }

            if (iD == daysM)
            {
                iD = 1;
                iMonth = iMonth + 1;
                iY = iY;
            }

            if ((iMonth == 12) && (iD == 31));
            {
                iD = 1;
                iMonth = 1;
                iY = iY + 1;
            }

    cout << iD << "-" << iMonth << "-" << iY << endl;
}

int main ()
{
    int  iDay, iMonth, iYear;

        cout << "Input day" << endl;
        cin >> iDay;

        cout << "Input Month" << endl;
        cin >> iMonth;

        cout << "Input Year" << endl;
        cin >> iYear;

        if (iDay >= 1 && iDay <= 31 && iMonth >= 1 && iMonth <= 12)
        {
            nextDay(iDay, iMonth, iYear);
        }
        else
            cout << "Invalid date." << endl;
}
```

My problem is that every single date just adds another year, regardless of the date. I'm wondering if its the conditioning of the nextDay function.. Any help will be appreciated! Thanks!~

Comment: What about leap-years?

Comment: As for your question, please show us some example input, the the corresponding actual *and* expected output. Also now would be a good time to learn how to use a debugger, and how to step through your code line by line (especially since there are some corner cases you don't handle correct and that would be very obvious if you learned stepping through the code).

Comment: I would recommend to fill the `struct tm` with your data, convert it to time_t, then add 1 day as a numberical operation, and then use `localtime` to convert it back to time_t. Then all nuances of date operations will be correct. This gives you only ~10 lines of code instead of the inventing the wheel. Reference: http://linux.die.net/man/3/mktime

Comment: Is your input actually an invalid date?   For example, 31st of Apriil (31 and 4) is invalid, but will pass your test as a valid date.   And there is a stray semi-colon in `nextDay()` which changes the meaning of your code.

Comment: You have a superflous semicolon at the last if condition in nextDay().

Answer (score 2):

```
if ((iMonth == 12) && (iD == 31));
//                              ^^^
```

That semicolon at the end of line makes the body of `if` statement empty, and the following block is always executed.